# Trying to sum and case when between max dates and max date - 7

Tags: sql, max, case-when

I am trying to sum a value in SQL when a date within the table is between max(date of another field)-7 and max(date of data).

Example:
sum(case when *date from table* between max(date from table)-7 and max(date from table) then *field to sum* else 0 end) as '0-7 Days'

Comment: you are almost there, are you getting error with your sql

Answer (score 0):

What you have is very close, this slight adjustment should do the trick.

```
DECLARE @DateFromTable DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @ValuetoSum INT = 5;

SELECT 
CASE WHEN @DateFromTable BETWEEN MAX(@DateFromTable) - 7 AND MAX(@DateFromTable) 
THEN SUM(@ValuetoSum) ELSE 0 END AS '0-7 Days'
```